# How to add XML node before and after set of nodes

Tags: c#, xml, for-xml-path

I'm looking for a way to add this node "LoanSecondaryStatusDates" at the beginning and its corresponding closing tag "LoanSecondaryStatusDates" to the end. I've produced the below using "FOR XML" in SQL server but can't figure out how to add the beginning and end tags.  If this is possible using "FOR XML" an example would be great, othwerwise C# would be fine. Thanks!

**Currently:**

```
<Loans>
    <Loan>
      <GUID></GUID>
      <AgentCompanyName></AgentCompanyName>
        <LoanSecondaryStatus>
            <StatusName>Name</StatusName>
            <StatusDate>Date</StatusDate>
        </LoanSecondaryStatus>
        <LoanSecondaryStatus>
            <StatusName>Name</StatusName>
            <StatusDate>Date</StatusDate>
        </LoanSecondaryStatus>
    </Loan>
</Loans>
```

**End result should be:**

```
 <Loans>
   <Loan>
   <GUID></GUID>
   <AgentCompanyName></AgentCompanyName>
    <LoanSecondaryStatusDates>
        <LoanSecondaryStatus>
            <StatusName>Name</StatusName>
            <StatusDate>Date</StatusDate>
    </LoanSecondaryStatus>
        <LoanSecondaryStatus>
            <StatusName>Name</StatusName>
            <StatusDate>Date</StatusDate>
        </LoanSecondaryStatus>
    </LoanSecondaryStatusDates>
</Loan>
</Loans>
```

**FOR XML Query**

```
SELECT 
   [GUID] 
  ,[AgentCompanyName],
   (
   SELECT 
    'Borrower Docs Sent/Req' as 'StatusName',
    CASE WHEN t.BorrowerDocsSent IS NOT NULL THEN t.BorrowerDocsSent ELSE '' END as 'StatusDate'

FROM Encompass_loanData as t
WHERE t.[GUID] = E.[GUID]
FOR XML PATH('LoanSecondaryStatus'), TYPE
  ),
  (
   SELECT 
    t.BorrowerCity as 'StatusName',
    t.[GUID] as 'StatusDate'

FROM Encompass_loanData as t
WHERE t.[GUID] = E.[GUID]
FOR XML PATH('LoanSecondaryStatus'), TYPE
  )

From Encompass_loanData E
FOR XML PATH ('Loan'), type, root('Loans')
```

**SQL Fiddle**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d672a/2/0

Answer (score 1):

The xml you have published does not have a valid root. So I added `<xml>` as the root.

This can be done quite easily in C# too. But this is a way to do it using xpath.

```
  <xml>
  <LoanSecondaryStatus>
    <StatusName>Name</StatusName>
    <StatusDate>Date</StatusDate>
  </LoanSecondaryStatus>
  <LoanSecondaryStatus>
    <StatusName>Name</StatusName>
    <StatusDate>Date</StatusDate>
  </LoanSecondaryStatus>
  </xml>
```

Here is the XSL.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <LoanSecondaryStatusDates>     
      <xsl:for-each select="xml/LoanSecondaryStatus">
        <LoanSecondaryStatus>
          <StatusName>
            <xsl:value-of select="StatusName"/>
          </StatusName>
          <StatusDate>
            <xsl:value-of select="StatusDate"/>
          </StatusDate>
        </LoanSecondaryStatus>
      </xsl:for-each>      
    </LoanSecondaryStatusDates>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LoanSecondaryStatusDates>
  <LoanSecondaryStatus>
    <StatusName>Name</StatusName>
    <StatusDate>Date</StatusDate>
  </LoanSecondaryStatus>
  <LoanSecondaryStatus>
    <StatusName>Name</StatusName>
    <StatusDate>Date</StatusDate>
  </LoanSecondaryStatus>
</LoanSecondaryStatusDates>
```

**Updated with SQL query**

```
SELECT 
   [GUID] 
  ,[AgentCompanyName],
   (
   SELECT NULL,   
            (
                SELECT 
                        'Borrower Docs Sent/Req' as 'StatusName',
                        CASE WHEN t.BorrowerDocsSent IS NOT NULL THEN t.BorrowerDocsSent ELSE '' END as 'StatusDate'
                FROM Encompass_loanData as t
                WHERE t.[GUID] = E.[GUID]
                FOR XML PATH('LoanSecondaryStatus'), TYPE
            ),
            (   
                SELECT NULL AS X
                FOR XML PATH('LoanSecondaryStatusDates'), TYPE
            ),
            (
                SELECT 
                        t.BorrowerCity as 'StatusName',
                        t.[GUID] as 'StatusDate'
                FROM Encompass_loanData as t
                WHERE t.[GUID] = E.[GUID]
                FOR XML PATH('LoanSecondaryStatus'), TYPE
            ),
            NULL
    FOR XML PATH('LoanSecondaryStatusDates'),TYPE
    )
    FROM Encompass_loanData E
    WHERE [LASTMODIFIED] >= '20160121'
    FOR XML PATH ('Loan'), type, root('Loans')
```

Comment: Thank you the XSL works, but it is stripping off other elements in the XML document.  Is there a way to keep the existing structure the same, but format only this section as above?

Comment: My apologies.  I've added the FOR XML query.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the XElement class, you'll be able to modify the xml tree easily with that.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx

http://www.dotnetperls.com/xelement

Answer (score 0):

I was able to wrap the child elements with this XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Loan">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::LoanSecondaryStatus)]"/>
            <LoanSecondaryStatusDates>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="LoanSecondaryStatus"/>
            </LoanSecondaryStatusDates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```